# LEFT JOIN conditions not affecting result

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a LEFT JOIN query with some conditions, but it seems to be acting strangely. It isn't being acted on by any of the ON clause conditions:

```
SELECT c.country_id, c.country_name, IFNULL(MAX(b.bid_amount),0)
FROM countries AS c
LEFT JOIN items_bids AS b
ON c.country_id = b.bid_country_id 
AND b.bid_removed = 0
LEFT JOIN advertisers AS a
ON a.advertiser_id = b.bid_advertiser_id 
AND a.advertiser_balance > 0
AND a.advertiser_review = 0
LEFT JOIN items AS n
ON b.bid_item_id = n.item_id
AND n.item_approved = 1
AND n.item_deleted = 0
AND n.item_paused = 0
GROUP BY c.country_name
```

It has the same result as this:

```
SELECT c.country_id, c.country_name, IFNULL(MAX(b.bid_amount),0)
FROM countries AS c
LEFT JOIN items_bids AS b
ON c.country_id = b.bid_country_id 
LEFT JOIN advertisers AS a
ON a.advertiser_id = b.bid_advertiser_id 
LEFT JOIN items AS n
ON b.bid_item_id = n.item_id
GROUP BY c.country_name
```

I'm sure it should be a different result, because if I put these conditions in a WHERE clause instead of an ON clause it does have an effect.

The thing is, I'm using a LEFT JOIN because I don't want to eliminate any countries from the result.

Comment: Can you include a small sample of data with the expected results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `on`-conditions don't work as you expect, because you use `left join` to join tables and then never use them so they have no effect. You only use `max(b.bid_amount)` and `countries`, so only conditions on `b` and `countries` will have an effect here.

E.g., if some rows for `advertisers` exist that fulfill your `on`-condition, they are joined but have no effect on `b.bid_amount` because you don't use them (they would have an effect on e.g. `count(*)` or `sum(b.bid_amount)` though). If no rows for `advertisers` exist, they have no effect on `b.bid_amount` either, because of the `left join`. So it doesn't matter what your conditions are.

Your first code is equivalent to

```
SELECT c.country_id, c.country_name, IFNULL(MAX(b.bid_amount),0)
FROM countries AS c
LEFT JOIN items_bids AS b
ON c.country_id = b.bid_country_id 
AND b.bid_removed = 0
GROUP BY c.country_name
```

and your second code is equivalent to

```
SELECT c.country_id, c.country_name, IFNULL(MAX(b.bid_amount),0)
FROM countries AS c
LEFT JOIN items_bids AS b
ON c.country_id = b.bid_country_id 
GROUP BY c.country_name
```

and it might not be surprising that they give the same result (depending on 
your data and how many rows have `b.bid_removed = 0`. Try `b.bid_removed = 1` and you might see an effect, it's the only relevant condition).

If you put your conditions, e.g. `AND a.advertiser_balance > 0` in a `where`-clause, mysql will only select rows where `a.advertiser_balance` is not null! So your `left join` will act as `join`, and it is not so surprising that this might have a different result.

Since you didn't describe what you actually wanted to achieve, I will take a wild guess and remove some left joins. You will get all countries, and all your `on`-conditions will work.

Try

```
SELECT c.country_id, c.country_name, IFNULL(MAX(b.bid_amount),0) 
FROM countries AS c
LEFT JOIN items_bids AS b
ON c.country_id = b.bid_country_id 
AND b.bid_removed = 0
JOIN advertisers AS a
ON a.advertiser_id = b.bid_advertiser_id 
AND a.advertiser_balance > 0
AND a.advertiser_review = 0
JOIN items AS n
ON b.bid_item_id = n.item_id
AND n.item_approved = 1
AND n.item_deleted = 0
AND n.item_paused = 0
GROUP BY c.country_name
```